# Android Gradle Plugin 2.2.0 ProGuard began to keep inner classes

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

After updating Android Studio to version 2.2 and Android Gradle plugin to 2.2.0, I have a lot of warnings when I build release apk, such as:

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(android.support.graphics.drawable.b) that doesn't come with an
>   Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

In addition, my release apk size has increased. So, I converted it to jar with dex2jar tool and compared with previous release (which was built with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3`). The first thing I noticed is that new release still have some inner classes, which was not in previous versions.

Then I add `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` to my proguard config to avoid warnings, but it increased file size much more by keeping all inner classes now.

So, can I build apk without unnecessary inner classes and `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` as it was in Android Gradle plugin 2.1.3?

ProGuard config:

```
# Retrolambda
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

# okhttp
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okio.**
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

# appcompat
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep public class * implements com.myapppackage.InterfaceClass
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod # was added to avoid 2.2.0 warnings

# Soft obfuscation
-keep public class !com.myapppackage.subpackage.** {
    public protected *;
}
```

Module build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
    }
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the default ProGuard rules included in Android Gradle plugin were changed in 2.2-beta2. The main changes were around `-keepattributes` and `-renamesourcefileattribute`.

We managed to fix it by copying the files `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-android-optimize.txt` that are included in the plugin, undo some of the changes and make the Gradle plugin use that instead:

```
proguardFiles 'proguard-android-modified.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

If you downgrade the version of the Android Gradle plugin to 2.2-beta1 and compare the ProGuard files then you'll see the differences (yes, these were not the only changes... there is a bunch of new `-keep` and `-keepclasseswithmembernames` rules too).

Comment: There are two official tickets for this so far: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222989 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222775